# What is the advantage of synchronized block in OkHttpClient's execute() method

Tags: java, exception, synchronized, okhttp

I'm reading the source code of OkHttp.
Here is the `execute()`in`RealCall.java`:

```
public Response execute() throws IOException {
    synchronized (this) {
      if (executed) throw new IllegalStateException("Already Executed");
      executed = true;
    }
    captureCallStackTrace();
    try {
      client.dispatcher().executed(this);
      Response result = getResponseWithInterceptorChain();
      if (result == null) throw new IOException("Canceled");
      return result;
    } finally {
      client.dispatcher().finished(this);
    }
  }
```

What is the advantage of synchronized ?

```
synchronized (this) {
      if (executed) throw new IllegalStateException("Already Executed");
      executed = true;
    }
```

I think there is nothing deferent to this code(no synchronized)

```
if (executed) throw new IllegalStateException("Already Executed");
executed = true;
```

For example , If there is three requests emit at the same time.
request one will go through,
request two will throw exception,
request three will not be execute.

Whether there is synchronized or not , code works no defferent !

So , why they write synchronized there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronized in this case ensures [thread safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety) by preventing *concurrent* access to the object by different threads.

`if (exectued)` within that block is simply checking whether or not the action has already occurred.